# @layer utilities is used but no matching @tailwind utilities directive is present

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, import, tailwind-css

I have a `Laravel 9` project and I want to use the `Tailwind`

When I put each `component`'s `css` in some files to separate them, it cause an error message but if I put all together works.

`Error message:`

**body.css `@layer components` is used but no matching `@tailwind components` directive is present.**

`app.css:`

```css
 @import "tailwind.css";

 @import "body.css";
```

`tailwind.css:`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

`body.css:`

```css
@layer components {
    .body {
        @apply bg-sky-100
    }
}
```

`webpack.mix.js:`

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
        // require('postcss-import'),
        require("tailwindcss/nesting"),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig({
        stats: {
            children: true,
        },
    })
    ;
```

`tailwind.config.js:`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
        "./resources/**/*.js",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
    darkMode: 'class',
    mode: "jit",

}
```

`package.json:`

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "10.4.7",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "postcss-import": "^14.1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Build-time imports](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports) to make sure @imports are handled before Tailwind processes them.

There is a section in the Tailwind docs that you can reference [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-multiple-css-files).

However, you already have `postcss-import` in your dependencies, you should uncomment it in `webpack.mix.js` and move it above Tailwind, and you should be good to go.

FYI, this is the recommended ordering (referenced in [nesting docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting)) otherwise you may run into some issues:

- postcss-import
- tailwindcss/nesting
- tailwindcss
- autoprefixer